# SQL Server fazer o select em uma tabela retornada pelo INFORMATION_ESCHEMA

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-temporária

Olá,

Preciso verificar todas as tabelas que contém uma mesma coluna e fazer uma logica para alterar todos os valores de todas essas colunas.

Estou tentando pegar o nome das tabelas da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @TABELA VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @TABELA = MIN ( TABLE_NAME ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'COD_COLUM'
print @TABELA

WHILE @TABELA IS NOT NULL
BEGIN   
    Select COD_COLUM from @Tabela

    SELECT @TABELA = MIN ( TABLE_NAME ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME > @TABELA  and 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'COD_COLUM'
END
```

Quando tento fazer isso, tenho o seguinte erro:
**Must declare the table variable "@TABELA".**

Eu não consigo pensar em nenhuma outra forma de fazer isso, alguém tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu script tem um erro ao atribuir o valor para a variável `@TABELA`, falta o `SELECT`, e se quer o primeiro registro, poderia usar `TOP`:

```
SELECT @TABELA = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'COD_COLUM')
```

De qualquer forma, esse `WHILE` não funciona, aliás, ele não tem sentido. Pelo que descreveu, para fazer isso e usar o `WHILE`, precisa usar um [`CURSOR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Com um cursor é possível fazer um laço `WHILE` e "fazer algo" para cada registro retornado.  Fica por exemplo assim:

```
-- declara a variável que vai ter o nome da tabela
DECLARE @TABELA VARCHAR(255)
-- declara o cursor
DECLARE tabelas_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'COD_COLUM'

-- abre o cursor  
OPEN tabelas_cursor  

-- pega o próxima valor na variável @TABELA
FETCH NEXT FROM tabelas_cursor INTO @TABELA

-- continua enquanto houver dados  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   -- faz alguma ação, aqui vou usar um SELECT, mas aqui coloque a sua lógica
   SELECT @TABELA

   -- pega o próximo registro
   FETCH NEXT FROM tabelas_cursor INTO @TABELA
END

-- ao fim, fecha e libera o cursor
CLOSE tabelas_cursor  
DEALLOCATE tabelas_cursor
```